# changing default program that opens a file using xdg-mime

Tags: ubuntu, xdg

I want to change the default program that opens `video/mp4` files using `xdg-mime` from `vlc.desktop` to the firefox browser, `firefox-firefox.desktop`. I tried following the instructions given [here](https://www.guyrutenberg.com/2018/01/20/set-default-application-using-xdg-mime/) however I had no luck. I ran the following two commands, the first of which I believe should change the default program. The second of which shows that this has not in fact been changed.

```
~$ xdg-mime default firefox-firefox.desktop video/mp4  
~$ xdg-mime query default video/mp4  
vlc.desktop
```

In case this is relevant, I am running `Ubuntu 22.04` as can be seen from the output of this command:

```
~$ lsb_release -a  
No LSB modules are available.  
Distributor ID: Ubuntu  
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04 LTS  
Release:        22.04  
Codename:       jammy
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why Firefox cannot be set to use `video/mp4` using `xdg-mime` is because its XDG desktop file (`firefox.desktop`) does not include `video/mp4` inside the `MimeType` key.

To override this behaviour, create your own user-specific `firefox.desktop` file from the system-wide file:

```
cp /snap/firefox/current/firefox.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/
```

If you are not using the Snap version of Firefox then this system-wide file should be found at `/usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop`.

Now you can set the default application for the MIME type:

```
xdg-mime default firefox.desktop video/mp4
```

Verify the default application is set:

```
xdg-mime query default video/mp4
```